# System not booting into Ubuntu partition after opening google chrome from terminal with sudo and --no-sandbox

Tags: google-chrome

I opened chrome and it didn't launch. I used the terminal to open it with sudo and got the message to use the --no-sandbox in addition to the main command. After I did that, the system became unstable and eventually crashed. It told me to log out, so I did, but nothing happened afterwards. Then I just hit the power button and the system turned off. After turning it back on, it tried to start up, but then started hanging with a simple message: `/dev/sda5: clean, 35784/1974272 files, 7517253/7891712 blocks`. After a while, the laptop (yes, laptop) fan turned off and no changes. I hit `Ctrl + Alt + Del` to restart and it did show the Ubuntu logo and said that it was restarting, but after restarting it was stuck at the same place.

No clue what to do now. I have a windows MAIN partition still available. I think that if I just reinstall the Ubuntu system it might work again but I don't know.

Help is very welcome as I have some big amounts (32 GB) of data on the Ubuntu partition.

Comment: mine failed to boot this morning, got to the grub menu and it seemed to boot but hung on ubuntu logo, without a busy icon. my quick solution was to clonezilla back the whole partition which takes me 15 mins. I keep /home on a separate partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what it was. The system does not boot when the partition is full. Deleting the chrome folder might have just made more free space for boot. Had this happen 2 times already.

Svenw

Answer (score 0):

Got it fixed just now. Found out that i had to delete the google chrome folder in `/opt/`. After rebooting it booted successfully. Very happy now. Had to use the Ubuntu live boot system. Now i know not to try and install google chrome.

Comment: It is unclear how exactly you installed Google Chrome, what caused your problem and why removing "the google chrome folder in `/opt/`" fixed your boot issue. (Maybe some file system was full?) I guess what you should learn isn't "not to try and install google chrome" but "*not to run programs as `root` if you don't know why running as `root` is necessary and why there is no other way to fix a permissions problem*" or "*not to install programs from sources other than the official package repositories unless you know what you are doing*"